# Natural partial order of Mitsch on Natural numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, semigroups, monoid

So according to Mitsch, the natural partial order $\leq$ of any semigroup $S$ is given by
$$a \leq b \iff a = xb = by, xa = a, \quad \text{for some } x, y \in S^1$$
But obviously in $(\mathbb N, \cdot)$ we have $2 \leq 3$, and yet there is no $x \in \mathbb N$ that satisfies the above condition.

Similarly in $(\mathbb N, +)$ we have $2 \leq 3$ and the same problem.

Is there something that I'm missing? Is regular "less than or equal" not a natural partial order on $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @npbm: To clean up this thread so as allow others to respond more easily, I'll delete all of my comments (and you can delete your responses to my comments). But you should edit your posted question to include a link to the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitsch is defining one particular partial order on any semigroup and calling it "the natural partial order".  This is nothing more than a name; it is not an assertion that any other partial orders are "unnnatural" in any sense.  As you have observed, in the case of $(\mathbb{N},\cdot)$ or $(\mathbb{N},+)$, it is not the same as the usual partial order of natural numbers.